# function number of executes and activation problem

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animate-cc

Below is the code for a simple match the letters with their shadow game.
4 letters, chosen randomly from all 24, show up on the screen, along with their shadows.

The letters are draggable and if they hit their shadow, they stick on it. The corresponding objects are named respectively: alfa, bita, gama, delta and their shadows: alfa_shadow etc.

For each letter a score corresponds: score1, score2, score 3, score4.
When a letter hits the shadow target, its score becomes 1, from 0.
Under the score adjust line there is a score trace line, just to check what’s going on.

There is also a score check function “score_check”, which checks if all four scores are 1, then it moves to the next scene.

I have two problems:

1.

The first time a letter is matched everything works fine.

The second time a letter is matched the trace line works twice

The third time a letter is matched the trace line works three times

The fourth time a letter is matched the trace line works four times.

This happens irrespective of the order by which I match the letters and shadows. I cannot understand why this happens, the code for each letter is exactly the same, changing only the names of variables and functions.

2. The score_check function never activates. I even tried replacing the && with || unsuccessfully.

Any ideas?

thanx

```
import flash.text.engine.EastAsianJustifier;
import flash.events.Event;

var gramata:Array = new Array(cpencil_1, cpencil_2, cpencil_3, cpencil_4, cpencil_5, cpencil_6, cpencil_7, cpencil_8, cpencil_9, cpencil_10, cpencil_11, cpencil_12, cpencil_13, cpencil_14, cpencil_15, cpencil_16, cpencil_17, cpencil_18, cpencil_19, cpencil_20, cpencil_21, cpencil_22, cpencil_23, cpencil_24);
var shadows:Array = new Array(shadow_01, shadow_02, shadow_03, shadow_04, shadow_05, shadow_06, shadow_07, shadow_08, shadow_09, shadow_10, shadow_11, shadow_12, shadow_13, shadow_14, shadow_15, shadow_16, shadow_17, shadow_18, shadow_19, shadow_20, shadow_21, shadow_22, shadow_23, shadow_24);
var gramata_choice:Array = [];
var shadow_choice:Array = [];
var choice:Array = [];
var score:Number = 0;
var score1:Number = 0;
var score2:Number = 0;
var score3:Number = 0;
var score4:Number = 0;


function score_check():void
{
    if(score1==1 && score2==1 && score3==1 && score4==1)
    {
            gotoAndStop(1, "Scene2");
    }
}

function dialekse_auto():void
{
    for (var i:uint=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        choice[i] = uint(Math.random()*gramata.length);
        gramata_choice[i] =  gramata[choice[i]];
        shadow_choice[i] =  shadows[choice[i]];
        trace(gramata_choice[i])
    }
}

function emfanise_auto():void
{
    var alfa_shadow = new shadow_choice[0];
    alfa_shadow.x = 300;
    alfa_shadow.y = 200;
    addChild(alfa_shadow);
    var alfa = new gramata_choice[0];
    alfa.x = 100;
    alfa.y = 400;
    addChild(alfa);
    alfa.mouseEnabled = enabled;
    alfa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traba);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stamata);
    function traba(e:Event):void
        {
            alfa.startDrag();
        }
    function stamata(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(alfa.hitTestObject(alfa_shadow))
            {
                alfa.stopDrag();
                alfa.x = 300;
                alfa.y = 200;
                score1 = 1;
                trace(score1);
            }
            else
            {
                    alfa.x = 100;
                    alfa.y = 400;
                    alfa.stopDrag();
            }
        }
    var bita_shadow = new shadow_choice[1];
    bita_shadow.x = 100;
    bita_shadow.y = 200;
    addChild(bita_shadow);
    var bita = new gramata_choice[1];
    bita.x = 200;
    bita.y = 400;
    addChild(bita);
    bita.mouseEnabled = enabled;
    bita.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traba2);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stamata2);
    function traba2(e:Event):void
        {
            bita.startDrag();
        }
    function stamata2(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            if(bita.hitTestObject(bita_shadow))
            {
                bita.x = 100;
                bita.y = 200;
                bita.stopDrag();
                score2 = 1;
                trace(score2);
            }
            else
            {
                bita.x = 200;
                bita.y = 400;
                bita.stopDrag();
            }
}
    var gama_shadow = new shadow_choice[2];
    gama_shadow.x = 400;
    gama_shadow.y = 200;
    addChild(gama_shadow);
    var gama = new gramata_choice[2];
    gama.x = 300;
    gama.y = 400;
    addChild(gama);
    gama.mouseEnabled = enabled;
    gama.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traba3);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stamata3);
    function traba3(e:Event):void
        {
            gama.startDrag();
        }
    function stamata3(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(gama.hitTestObject(gama_shadow))
            {
                gama.stopDrag();
                gama.x = 400;
                gama.y = 200;
                score3 = 1;
                trace(score3);
            }
            else
            {
                gama.x = 300;
                gama.y = 400;
                gama.stopDrag();
            }
        }
    var delta_shadow = new shadow_choice[3];
    delta_shadow.x = 200;
    delta_shadow.y = 200;
    addChild(delta_shadow);
    var delta = new gramata_choice[3];
    delta.x = 400;
    delta.y = 400;
    addChild(delta);
    delta.mouseEnabled = enabled;
    delta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traba4);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stamata4);
    function traba4(e:Event):void
        {
            delta.startDrag();
        }
    function stamata4(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(delta.hitTestObject(delta_shadow))
            {
                delta.stopDrag();
                delta.x = 200;
                delta.y = 200;
                score4 = 1;
                trace(score4);
            }
            else
            {
                delta.x = 400;
                delta.y = 400;
                delta.stopDrag();
            }
        }
}

score_check();
dialekse_auto();
emfanise_auto();

stop();
```

Comment: Your code is very long and not algorithmic. You work with each letter separately, with totally no regard to the fact that each pair "letter - shadow" is absolutely the same. There's no point to look where's the problem withing that script - the whole script is the problem. I answered another "drag many objects to many targets" post, you should start with adapting it (setting up objects and targets) for your own case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249946/4687633 Also, creation part, you should either design them onto stage, or at least devise creation into a loop.

Comment: Thanks @Organis you are always helpful! I checked that post and you have very nicely explained code. I will try to implement. You are quite right about the creation too. I usually start writing code in a dumb way, just to check that I understand the logic but I make it harder for myself it seems.