# how to hittestObject multiple movie clips at the same time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a simple drag and drop to the target system it works fine except I don't someone to be able to drop where there is a movie clip already. decided to hittestObject on the target to check if there is a movie clip there. in if there is it just sends the object back to its original position. however, when I try to code the same thing for more than one object it only works on one of the objects.

I've tried putting my objects in an array and putting them in a variable however I can only hittestobject one object in the array or variable at a time when I need to hitestobject multiple objects at the same time. Please help

```
    if (char2.hitTestObject(target0))
    {
        slot0=true;
    }

    if (!char2.hitTestObject(target0))
    {
        slot0=false;
    }

        if (char2.hitTestObject(target1))
    {
        slot1=true;
    }

    if (!char2.hitTestObject(target1))
    {
        slot1=false;
    }

        if (char2.hitTestObject(target2))
    {
        slot2=true;
    }

    if (!char2.hitTestObject(target2))
    {
        slot2=false;
    }
```

I need to also hittestobject on char1 and char0. this code works however if I try to simply duplicate the code and replace char2 with char1 only one other code blocks with work please help. Also an alternative like

```
if (char2 || char1.hitTestObject(target0))
{
    slot0=true;
}
```

would work that would be helpful. please help show me how to do it or let me know if it's even possible. thank you!!

Full Code:

```
var slot0:Boolean;
var slot1:Boolean;
var slot2:Boolean;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler(et:Event):void
{
trace(slot0);
}
// Unlike the Object class, that allows String keys only
// the Dictionary class allows you to store and
// access data by the object instance.
var theValids:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
var theCharacters:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
// We'll store the original (x,y) coordinates here.
var theOrigin:Point = new Point;
// The Sprite class is the superclass of MovieClip, furthermore,
// the startDrag method defined for Sprite class, so unless you
// create your own dragging code, you are bound to use Sprites,
// while you cannot drag SimpleButtons and TextFields this way.
// We'll store the current dragged object here.
var theObject:Sprite;
var theChar:Sprite;

// This first argument is the object you want to be draggable.
// The "...targets:Array" means you can call this method with
// any number of arguments, the first one is mandatory, the
// rest will be passed in a form of Array (empty Array if you
// call this method with a single argument).
function setupDraggable(source:Sprite, ...targets:Array):void
{
    // Make the object draggable.
    source.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
    source.mouseChildren = false;
    source.mouseEnabled = true;
    source.buttonMode = true;

    // Keep the list of the object's targets so it can be
    // retrieved later by the key of the object itself.
    theValids[source] = targets;
}
// Ok, let's setup the objects and link them to their designated
// targets. The whole point of the rest of the code is to make
// this one part as simple as it possible: you just edit
// these lines to tell which one objects go where.
// This object can be dropped to a single target.
// setupDraggable(obj_1 , target1);

// These objects can go to two targets each.
// setupDraggable(obj_10, target1, target10);
// setupDraggable(obj_2 , target2, target20);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setslot1);
function setslot1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (character1.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=true;
        }
        if (!character1.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=false;
        }
            if (character1.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=true;
        }
        if (!character1.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=false;
        }
            if (character1.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=true;
        }
        if (!character1.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=false;
        }
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setslot2);
function setslot2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (character0.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=true;
        }
        if (!character0.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=false;
        }
            if (character0.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=true;
        }
        if (!character0.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=false;
        }
            if (character0.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=true;
        }
        if (!character0.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=false;
        }
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, setslot3);
function setslot3(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if (char2.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=false;
        }
            if (char2.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=false;
        }
            if (char2.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=false;
        }
}
// This one object can be dropped to any of targets.
setupDraggable(character0, target0, target1, target2, redslot);
setupDraggable(character1, target0, target1, target2, greenslot);
setupDraggable(char2, target0, target1, target2, blueslot);
// The MOUSE_DOWN event handler.

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{       
        if (char2.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
            slot0=false;
        }
            if (char2.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
            slot1=false;
        }
            if (char2.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=true;
        }
        if (!char2.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
            slot2=false;
        }

// Clean-up. Remove the reference, the object is no longer
    // being dragged, so you won't need to keep it.
    //theObject = null;

    // Get the reference to the object under the mouse.
    theObject = e.currentTarget as Sprite;

    // Keep the object's initial position.
    theOrigin.x = theObject.x;
    theOrigin.y = theObject.y;

    // Put the dragged object on top of anything else.
    // We are operating in the parent context of all these
    // objects here so there's no need to address anObj.parent.
    setChildIndex(theObject, numChildren - 1);

    // Start dragging.
    theObject.startDrag(true);

    // Listen to the MOUSE_UP event, which could happen offstage
    // and out of the dragged object, so the only reliable
    // way is to listen it from the Stage. That's why we
    // are keeping theObject reference as an additional
    // variable, without relying on event's data.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}

// The MOUSE_UP event handler.
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{   

    // Unsubscribe the MOUSE_UP event handler.
    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);

    // Stop the dragging process.
    theObject.stopDrag();

    // Let's assume there could be more than a single collision.
    // We need to figure the one target that is closest.
    var theTarget:DisplayObject;
    var theDistance:int = 100000;

    // Store the dragged object position so we can
    // measure distances to the valid collisions, if any.
    var thePlace:Point = theObject.localToGlobal(new Point);


    // Now, the magic. Lets browse through the
    // valid targets and see if there's a collision.
    for each (var aTarget:DisplayObject in theValids[theObject])
    {

        if (theObject.hitTestObject(aTarget))
        {

            // Let's see if the current collision is closer
            // to the dragged object, than the previous one
            // (if any, that's what initial 100000 for).
            var aPlace:Point = aTarget.localToGlobal(new Point);
            var aDistance:int = Point.distance(aPlace, thePlace);

            if (aDistance < theDistance)
            {
                theTarget = aTarget;
                theDistance = aDistance;
            }
        }
    }
    // If there's at least one collision,
    // this variable will not be empty.

   if (theTarget)
    {
                // Make the object non-interactive.
        // theObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
        // theObject.mouseEnabled = false;
        // theObject.buttonMode = false;
        // Glue the dragged object to the center of the target.
        theObject.x = theTarget.x;
        theObject.y = theTarget.y;
    }

    else
    {
        // If we're here, that means there was no valid collisions,
        // lets return the object to its designated place.
        theObject.x = theOrigin.x;
        theObject.y = theOrigin.y;
    }
    if(slot0==true){

    if (theObject.hitTestObject(target0))
        {
        theObject.x = theOrigin.x;
        theObject.y = theOrigin.y;
        }
}
if(slot1==true){

    if (theObject.hitTestObject(target1))
        {
        theObject.x = theOrigin.x;
        theObject.y = theOrigin.y;
        }
}
if(slot2==true){

    if (theObject.hitTestObject(target2))
        {
        theObject.x = theOrigin.x;
        theObject.y = theOrigin.y;
        }
}
// Clean-up. Remove the reference, the object is no longer
    // being dragged, so you won't need to keep it.
    //theObject = null;
}
```

Only setslot3 works setslot 1&2 dont work and this happens anytime i put more than one of this specific code.

Comment: Not too long ago I devised a simple drag-many-objects-to-drop-on-many-targets system, you're free to take it and modify as you see fit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249946/4687633

Comment: @Organis hey Organis im actual im actually using that your system works well, i have it set up where three objects can go to any three targets. it works however if i just do that it can place two objects on the same target and the top one covers the bottom one. what im trying to achieve is if there is already and object on a target than the object im trying to place with just return to its previous position/origin. maybe you could help especially because im using your system. I edited and posted my full code can you please have a look at it.

Comment: Then you obviously went a wrong way. All you need to achieve the thing you want is to list all taken targets and ignore them in the **for .. each** loop.